# LibGdx setOrigin() not working

Tags: libgdx

I know the difference between setX/Y and setOrigin and I'm pretty sure I actually am using setOrigin() correctly. I want this button to enlarge while touched. Right now scaleBy() seems to be scaling from the lower left, enlarging it slightly and moving it up and to the right. Resetting the origin or trying to move it manually through another action has no apparent effect. See screenshots below for more clarity.

```
final Group but = new Group();
//...
//this seems to have no effect
but.setOrigin(but.getWidth()/2, but.getHeight()/2); //center origin for scaling
but.addListener(new InputListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
        //this happens
        but.addAction(Actions.scaleBy(.2f, .2f));
        //this doesn't
        but.addAction(Actions.moveBy(but.getWidth(), but.getHeight()));
        return true;
    }
    //...
});
stage.addActor(but);
```

Before touch:

[image]

After touch:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to set Size of your group.

```
but.addAction(Actions.moveBy(but.getWidth(), but.getHeight()));
```

This code is not working because you're not setting size of your but group object.
`but.getWidth()` and `but.getHeight()` return zero so `but` group remain in same position after you're applying action.

Comment: Thanks! Apparently setting the size of actors and adding them to the group doesn't affect the bounds of the group (I figured a group would automatically have bounds equal to the sum of its children)